# Examples of how to create text fields, size them, and put them in columns on a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, report, creation, cells

The 1,500 page Access 97 Bible (don't laugh!) that I've been given by my boss to solve his problem doesn't solve my problem of how to solve his problem, because it has nee VBA code.

Let me first make clear that I've made attempts to solve this without (much) coding, and that I've coded quite a bit in VBA already, so I'm basically familiar with most things including recordsets, queries, etc etc but have problems with MS Access limits on how to form a report with data coming from VBA variables. I'm also versatile in most programming languages, but this is not a language problem but rather a "how to/what's possible" problem.

My problem right now is that dragging the query fields into the Detail subform and putting them into cells in columns setting Left and Top with VBA code are moving them alright, but each cell is on a new page. Unfortunately, there is multiple data in each cell that won't conform to the Create Report Guide options available.

So my question is simply this: **Can someone point me to working examples of code that create, place, and fill with VBA variable strings, text fields at any coordinate I please on a paper size of my choice?**

Edit: The above is not an option, as I understand this will prohibit the client from getting an .mde database. What remains, then, is to merely ask for some sound advice on how to get several rows GROUPed BY weekday and machine (see below) into a recordset or similar for each cell. I guess the best way is to count the number of columns in the table (machines in the sql result) and create 5 rows of these with dummy data, then go through the result rows and place the data in the relevant controls. But if you have ideas for doing this work better and faster, write them as answers.

Sorry for this, I knew there was something I wasn't understanding. Basically, I thought Access supported creating reports dynamically via VBA, ie. "generating pages with data" rather than "preparing a flow of controls connected to datasources". But Access requires that you create an ample amount of dummy, unlinked controls manually, then either fill or hide them and that's how they become "dynamic".

This is for Access 2003 on a remote server accessing local and remote ODBC SQL database tables, if relevant. **The goal is to make a week schedule of n columns (n=number of machines at a certain plant) x 5 rows (weekday Mon-Fri), and put 1 or more recordset rows (=scheduled activities for that day on that machine) in each of the "n by 5 table" cells.**

If you detect venting frustration in this post I can only ask your forgiveness and hope for your understanding.

Comment: Seems awkward to have machines go across the page in columns? 2 machines would be 2 columns and much wasted paper space. 15 machines would suggest fonts and text boxes too small to be of use. Would  not 7 weekdays across the top like any calendar and then n- machines rows going down work better? This setup is also much easy in Access. Going across suggests column sizes will NEVER be consistent and this means no pre-printed forms or OCR systems or any kind of automated scanning of job numbers or bar codes from those sheets.  Such layouts are thus easier to read by both humans and machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- Create many objects manually (grr!)
- name them systematically
- put them in a Control Array (get all Me.Controls, sift out the ones you're interested in, and put them in an indexed array)
- go through the array and change their properties

Answer (score 0):

So, has many techniques for this:
Ex: 1) using dinamic sql for this:
'Create a function to make sql query
    Function MakeMySQlReport(Parameters):
    Dim strSql as string
    Dim strMyVar as string

```
    strsql = vbnullstring
    strsql = "Select " & myVar1 & " as MyFieldVar1, * from myTable where Fieldx =" & Parameters
    MyReport.recordSource = ssql
End Function
```

Ex: 2) create function that returns yours strings:

```
Function MyString1() as string
    MyString1 = 'ABC'
end Function
```

An in your report, select the textbox will receive the value and type =MyString1()]

I hope this help to you, need more examples?

Comment: No, this part I know already! I need to parse the query result rows (no problem) and based on the row data create & place text fields dynamically (problem).